# Get Broadcast receiver when Gmail Account Synck Complete

Tags: android

I am working on a android app where it is needed that My application should get a broadcast receiver intent when Gmail account synck completed How i can do this please tell me

```
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls"), true, gmailObserver);
```